# "share_target" does not work in my PWA app

Tags: javascript, android, html, progressive-web-apps

I created a simple page with manifest.json (https://island-dapper-patella.glitch.me)

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "theme_color": "#ff0000",
  "background_color": "#ff0000",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/share.html",
    "params": {
      "title": "name",
      "text": "description",
      "url": "link"
    }
  }
}
```

I installed it on my smartphone (Android, Chrome 84), its icon appeared on the apps list.

But when I selected a text, and go to Share Menu I hadn't my PWA app there.

Why?

EDIT: Also I don't have an "Install" item in desktop Chrome. Maybe something is wrong?

Comment: Run the chrome lighthouse tool. It will tell you what you need to fix to make it a valid PWA. You have some issues there.

Answer (score 0):

I see your manifest.json missing some entries for share target.

Make sure it should be like this.

```
"share_target": {
"action": "url to get data",
"enctype": "multipart/form-data",
"method": "POST",
"params": {
  "title": "title",
  "text": "text",
  "url": "url",
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "media[]",
      "accept": [
        "audio/*",
        "image/*",
        "video/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

}

I am using this and it workes successfully. (yes with file uploading image, audio and video, you can add more [mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types))

You need to make sure of following.
**The sharing should contain the name properly only then it will get the details.**

```
"params": {
  "title": "name",
  "text": "description",
  "url": "link"
}
```

And you can conclude your test through this url : https://w3c.github.io/web-share/demos/share-files.html

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you were also missing an "install" item in desktop Chrome. It looks like your `manifest.json` is missing the required `start_url` field.

Here's a list of fields MDN says is required for making a PWA installable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Guides/Making_PWAs_installable#required_manifest_members

This may or may not solve your `share_target` issue, but I figured it was worth mentioning since you noted the PWA installation issue.